# Declare multiple objects in one definition

Tags: xtext

I am new to Xtext and I would like to be able to have declarations like

`class A, B, C{
  Some common features
}`

and be able to refer to A, B and C. 
I tried to do it like `'class' name +=ID (',' name += ID)*` but this wont work since no object are apparently created. I assume I have to use actions but I don't understand how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: the solution for that highly depends on other features you need/have.
you can adapt IDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy to index the same object under multiple names e.g. or you can use IDerivedStateComputer to create some artificial objects...

Comment: I am not sure what features i need since they may come up by time. I just started the DSL. For now I need them to be referable. Is there any doc except what is in Xtext docs on their page on this? So the syntax for creating such objects in xtext is correct? Or if it's not hard, you can just tel me pros and cons of both your approaches. Thanks.

Comment: dont know any but have a look/debug `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy.createEObjectDescriptions(EObject, IAcceptor<IEObjectDescription>)` and simply calculate multiple names. the grammar then may be `names+=ID (',' names+=ID)*`